# Will monosodium dihydrogen phosphate react as base or acid in water?

Tags: acid-base

Will $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ react as as an acid or a base if you make it react with water?

I got stuck here. I can figure out the reaction:

$$\ce{NaH2PO4 + H2O -> Na^+ + H2PO4^- + H2O}$$

But when I look $\ce{H2PO4^{-}}$ up, it says that it can both be an acid and a base. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monosodium dihydrogen phosphate, $\ce{H2PO4^-}$, is an amphoteric species and it will act as both an acid and a base. 
These are the related chemical equations:

\begin{align}
  \ce{H2PO4- + H2O &<=> HPO4^2- + H3O+}  & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} &= 7.21\\
  \ce{H2PO4- + H2O &<=> H3PO4 + OH-}     & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} &= 11.88
\end{align}

As an example, $\pu{0.1 M}$ solution of such a salt will have a pH of about $4.7$.
In other words, the acidic behaviour dominates over the alkaline one. This is due to the value of $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=7.21$ (related to the acidic behaviour) compared to the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}=11.88$ (related to the alkaline behaviour).

Comment: Wouldn't it be acidic on every concentration in water?

Comment: Acidic yes,  but pH would vary with concentration although slightly.

Comment: if acidic behavior dominates, why would it be amphoteric ?